# When using UXRVT on Arch Linux color codes only working for root user, but not for normal users

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, rxvt

I used .Xservice to do some custom color codes, however the color codes only appear for the root user and not for normal users.

My .Xservice file looks like this:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Fira Code:size=16
URxvt.boldFont:xft:Fira Code:size=16
URxvt.letterSpace: -1
URxvt.scrollBar: false

URxvt*background: #14202E
URxvt*foreground: #dbe6ec

URxvt*colorUL: #86a2b0

! black
URxvt*color0  : #2E3436
URxvt*color8  : #555753
! red
URxvt*color1  : #CC0000
URxvt*color9  : #34E2E2
! green
URxvt*color2  : #16c98d
URxvt*color10 : #0fdebd
! yellow
URxvt*color3  : #FFDF01
URxvt*color11 : #feef6d
! blue
URxvt*color4  : #3465A4
URxvt*color12 : #729FCF
! magenta
URxvt*color5  : #75507B
URxvt*color13 : #AD7FA8
! cyan
URxvt*color6  : #06989A
URxvt*color14 : #34E2E2
! white
URxvt*color7  : #D3D7CF
URxvt*color15 : #EEEEEC
```

What a normal user looks like:

[image: normal user terminal]

What the root user looks like:

[image: root user terminal]

How do I get the color codes to appear for the normal user as well?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the file is called `.Xresources` (but you technically could use `.Xservice`). To (re)load the settings you have to call the command:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Put this command into the startup script of your DE/WM to apply your settings when you boot.

More information is listed here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x_resources